# red: path o/a is not valid for integer! type

Tags: red

This code works:

```
  o: context [
    a: 1
  ]

  o/a
```

This one doesn't:

```
  o: context [
    a: 1
    return a
  ]
  o
  o/a
```

> *** Script Error: path o/a is not valid for integer! type
>   *** Where: catch
>   *** Stack:

Is there a way to make the second one work ?

Answer (score 4):

`return` will force its function to return whatever value is provided. The thing is that `context` is a function too! So, when you do:

```
o: context [
    a: 1
    return a
]
```

`o` word will be set to a returned value from a `context` function, which takes a block, evaluates it according to `make object! ...` semantics (see details [here](https://github.com/meijeru/red.specs-public/blob/master/specs.adoc#code-object-code)), and returns a `1` integer in the process, because that's what you've asked it to do.

I'm not quite sure what else you've expected in this case. If you want o set `o` to an actual `object!` -- just don't use `return`.

Comment: I wanted O to return AND be able to call any O methods.

Comment: i.e. you want `o` to be an integer AND an object at the same time..?

Comment: Or do you want to set `o` to an object, but return a value of its `a` field as a result of the whole expression? `get in o: object [a: 1] 'a` ?

Comment: O is an Object, I want to access a child implicitely: MSAccess VBA allowed this without requiring explicitely to name the default child.